# ReactJS - Appending POST response

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm fairly new to ReactJS and I'm trying to figure out the best way to append and present my recently created record without having to refresh my page. Currently my rout has a redirect which makes sense why the triggered post via `postComment()` is refreshing the page, but I'm curious how I should 1) modify my successful POST route to send a JSON message for React use and not refresh and 2) update my comments section with the newly created comment. Should I convert my `Comments` component into a state to handle the change?

*(Note: The comment component is a module with `Comments` being populated with an array being passed from separate file)*

**Comments Logic:**

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

//Record Comment - Comment
const Comment = props => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <h5>{props.user_id}</h5>
                <h4>{props.comment}</h4>
                <h3>{props.app_user.fullNameSlug}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} 

//Record Comment - Comment Form
class CommentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    postComment(comment) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/record/:recordId/comment', { method: 'POST', body: comment})
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        alert('This is the submit ' + this.state.value);
        postComment();
        e.preventDefault();

    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="record-comment__form">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <label>Comment:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                        <form action={"/app/record/" + this.props.recordId + "/comment"} method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props.csrf}/>
                            <div className="col-md-9">
                                <textarea name="comment" className="record-comment__form-text-area" onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })} value={this.state.value}></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <button type="submit" className="record-comment__form-button" disabled={!this.state.value}>Comment</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//Record Comment - Container
export default class Comments extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="record-comment-container">
                <CommentForm recordId={this.props.recordId} csrf={this.props.csrf}/>
                { this.props.record_comments.map((comment, i) => 
                    <Comment {...comment} key={this.props.recordCommentId}/>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**ExpressJS Route:**

```
//POST /record/:recordId/comment
exports.create = function(req, res){
    var hashids = new Hashids('record', 10);
    var decodedHash = hashids.decode(req.params.recordId);
    var annotationId = decodedHash[0];

    models.RecordComment.create({
        comment: req.body.comment,
        commentId: commentId,
        userId: req.user.userId
    }).then(function(){
        req.flash('success', 'Comment was successfully created');
        res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make some changes in your `postComment()` method and in the states. Like this

```
   //Record Comment - Comment Form
    class CommentForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                value: '',
                comments:[]
            };
            this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        postComment(comment) {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/record/:recordId/comment', { method: 'POST', body: comment})
                .then(res => {
                    return res.json();
                })  
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    let oldComments = this.state.comments;
                    this.setState({comments:oldComments.concat(data)});
                }) 
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
   onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        alert('This is the submit ' + this.state.value);
        this.postComment();
        e.preventDefault();

    }
```

In the Routes you will have to send/retrieve the saved object. Therefore try something like this

```
//POST /record/:recordId/comment
exports.create = function(req, res){
    var hashids = new Hashids('record', 10);
    var decodedHash = hashids.decode(req.params.recordId);
    var annotationId = decodedHash[0];

    let reccoment = new RecordComment({
        comment: req.body.comment,
        commentId: commentId,
        userId: req.user.userId
    });
    reccoment.save(function(err,comment){
              res.json(comment);
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I get an error at `oldComments.concat(data)`

Comment: @cphill can you post the error message you got while running the code?. Btw i updated the code a bit

Comment: Ahh your fix of making it an object and modifying the property removed the error from webpack, but the error from my console is when `postComment()` is triggered. `Uncaught ReferenceError: postComment is not defined`. Coming from the `handleSubmit()` function.

Comment: @cphill i made some changes to my answers you have forgotten to use **this**( this.postComment();) keyword which refers to the correct context that the function is referencing.